# Creating NX plugin for generating a single file

Tags: javascript, nrwl-nx

I would like to create my first nx plugin, which only adds a generated file to the application in the dist folder.

So this is the basicly the script as I did it before. But as nx plugins are new for me, I do not understand the difference between generator and executor (which is explained in the [docs](https://nx.dev/l/n/core-concepts/nx-devkit)) at all.

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { promisify } from 'util'
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile)

function generateContent() {
  return { foo: 'bar' }
}

async function generateFile(filePath, content) {
  try {
    await writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(content, null, 2) + '\r\n')
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error('Could not write file: ' + filePath)
  }
}

const run = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const content = generateContent()
    await generateFile('dist/apps/my-app/file.json', content)
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(error)
  }
}

run()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

So if I understand it correctly, I have to put the above code in the `executor` - replacing the `console.log` line, right?

But writing the file itself has to be added to the generator, so I don't need `writeFile`, right?

**executor.ts**

```
import { BuildExecutorSchema } from './schema'

export default async function runExecutor(options: BuildExecutorSchema) {
  console.log('Executor ran for Build', options)
  return {
    success: true
  }
}
```

But I am using

```
run()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

as a starting point in my script. How should this look like in the executor?

An example for this very basic plugin code would be very helpful for my understanding.

Comment: Have you missed await near `generateFile('dist/apps/my-app/file.json', content)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: Links to NX documentation also should be useful in the question itself.

Comment: As I see from the [doc](https://nx.dev/l/n/executors/creating-custom-builders), there should be special wrapping for attaching executors. So how do you launch them? Could you please describe more your use-case and project structure?

Comment: It should be as simple as possible. I just want to create a config.json file, with some generated parameters inside, like app name and path to dist folder. The plugin will be used in a CI pipeline.